# R Cross Validation lm predict function

Tags: r, cross-validation, prediction, lm

I have a problem with a cross validation I am doing right now. I have a dataset and split it into 4 pieces randomly, choose 3 of them for a regression model and use the 4th left one to model my target value. So far I always used a manual methode, but this is a lot of work, so I wanted to try the predict function in lm. But I never get the same results when I compare the values.

Here is my dataset:

```
df = mtcars
subs = 4
set.seed(5)
idx <- gl(n = subs,round(nrow(df)/subs)) 
df = split(df, sample(idx))
names(df) = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")

df_split= rbind(df$S1, df$S2)
df_split = rbind(df_split, df$S3)
```

I am doing the regression like this:

```
Regression <- lm(df_split$mpg ~ df_split$cyl + df_split$disp + df_split$hp + df_split$drat + df_split$wt
                 + df_split$qsec)

summary(Regression)
StepRegression = step(Regression,direction="both")
finalmod = as.character(StepRegression$call)[2]
OptiRegression = lm(finalmod)
Regression_Summary= as.data.frame (summary(OptiRegression)$coefficient)
Regression_Summary$RSquared = summary(OptiRegression)$r.squared
Regression_Summary$AdjRSquared = summary(OptiRegression)$adj.r.squared
```

Now here is my manual methode to calculate the mpg of my 4th subset:

```
gridnames = str_sub(rownames(Regression_Summary)[-1], start = 10)

Model_manual <- ((as.matrix(df$S4[, gridnames]) %*%
                 Regression_Summary[-1, 1]) + Regression_Summary[1, 1])[,1]

Model_manual = as.data.frame(Model_manual)

Model_manual 
    Datsun 710       25.23129
    Merc 280         19.72129
    Merc 280C        19.72129
    Merc 450SL       16.11353
    Merc 450SLC      15.97497
    Fiat 128         25.96176
    Toyota Corolla   26.98801
    Porsche 914-2    25.75960
```

I tried the predict() function to aviod too much work. But I never get the same result and also I always get warnings and a different lenght.

```
predict(OptiRegression, df$S4[, gridnames], type = "response")
 1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12       13 
22.18532 16.99089 11.53276 10.90318 27.78928 15.86852 16.42750 20.81169 20.53641 15.59900 15.17130 24.77051 17.13763 
      14       15       16       17       18       19       20       21       22       23       24 
14.85076 14.27263 23.72070 21.47865 19.93114 23.27714 22.90166 10.90105 17.37318 26.69614 27.17296
```

What I am doing wrong? I am pretty sure that my manual methode is correct. Can somebody please give me some support?

Comment: You shouldn't use `df_split$` in your formula to `lm()`. That hard codes the result to that data.frame so you can't use `predict()` in the results. Instead use `Regression <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec, data=df_split)` where you pass the data.frame as the `data=` parameter. Then you as just tied to column names and not a data source.

Comment: Is this my only mistake? And is my manual calculation correct?